# Why do I keep getting NULL results?

Tags: sql, null, qlikview

For some reason I keep getting NULL results included in my data. It has been narrowed down to a section of the script:

```
Goods_In
    LOAD
    WEL_ORIG &'/' & WEL_EINGANG AS GI_Number,
    WEL_RECHNUNG AS SI_Fut_Invoice_No;
```

SQL

```
SELECT * 
FROM CONFUTHO.dbo.V_WE_LINK 
WHERE WEL_RECHNUNG > 133695 and WEL_RECHNUNG is NOT NULL;
```

And a small section of the results are as follows;

```
SI_Fut_Invoice_No    GI_Number
                      67715
                      67716
                      67717
                      67718
                      67719
                      67720
                      67721
144608             1/247336
144605             1/247337
144606             1/247338
144604             1/247339
144607             1/247340
145611             1/247341
149074             1/247341
144816             1/247342
```

As you can see I am still getting `GI_Numbers` with NULL WEL_ORIG and `WEL_RECHNUNG`. I am relatively new to Qlikview, do they have an alternative for NOT NULL?

Comment: I tried formatting,I am not sure of what does Goods_In mean,please edit

Comment: Are you sure those values `WEL_RECHNUNG` contains are `null`? might it be that they are empty strings? Is `V_WE_LINK` a view? Maybe add it's code too. Also - we can't see that you get `null` in those fields - you don't show those fields in your output section

Comment: Not sure what you mean, some rows have a GI_Number with no corresponding SI_Fut_Invoice_No or WEL_ORIG number. I am not sure why the rows with no SI_Fut_Invoice_No value are in the output.

NB. Goods_In: is just the table name

Comment: @KMoe - but then - you are doing `where WEL_RECHNUNG  is not null` instead of the `SI_Fut_Invoice_No` field

Comment: I just renamed it SI_Fut_Invoice_No because it was in German

'WEL_RECHNUNG AS SI_Fut_Invoice_No'

Comment: So back to the original question - are you certain these are `null`s and not empty strings?

Comment: Still get the same results if I use !=""

Comment: It might be a string of size > "". That field seems to be of some length when WEL_ORIG is empty. Try to check where len(trim(WEL_RECHNUNG)) > 0

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution could be :

```
LET inacceptable_value = -1 ;

Goods_In :
NoConcatenate
LOAD
    *
WHERE GI_Number <> '$(inacceptable_value)' ;
LOAD
    alt( WEL_ORIG &'/' & WEL_EINGANG , '$(inacceptable_value)' ) 
        AS GI_Number ,
    WEL_RECHNUNG AS SI_Fut_Invoice_No
;
```